# Password protect entire CodeIgniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to password protect an entire CodeIgniter site, but not with HTTP basic authentication (.htaccess in Apache, I'm using Nginx anyway).

What I'd like to have is a CodeIgniter-powered login page that gates access to the entire site. If the user is logged in, then the CodeIgniter routing engine is still used as it would be if I didn't have this login page.

I could place logic at the beginning of every controller that redirects to the login page if the user is not logged-in, but this is error-prone, as this is a large project that's being worked on by many developers. If for some reason this logic is missing then an anonymous user could access some parts of the application.

I think what I want is something that's executed before routing, that checks if a user is logged-in. Is there a standard way to hook in code at this point?

Comment: Create MY_Controller in core folder, lock your work from there & extend from it in all your other controllers.

Comment: Yes, I decided to implement a solution based on this blog post http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth

Answer (score 1):

In large scale projects built on a codeigniter I would consider handling security (and other cross cutting concerns, like logging for example) by using a AOP class, triggered via CI hooks. There are few opensource AOP libs out there, or you can write your own lightweight solution.

[A very basic explanation of what AOP is and how it could be done in CI you can read here](http://www.sitepoint.com/explore-aspect-oriented-programming-with-codeigniter-1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's part of my code. It works great for me :)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Inside extends CI_Controller {

```
private $secured = array('index', 'stats', 'completed', 'calculator', 'howitworks', 'inprogress');
public $data;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // Loading library, helpers and models.
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model(array('world_trade', 'user_model', 'calculate', 'core_operations'));

    if(in_array($this->uri->rsegment(2), $this->secured))
    {
        if(!$this->user_model->is_login())
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }
```

user model:

```
    public function is_login()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only 2. User action : login/register and this one. Why Did you ask me?

Comment: I have an application with many controllers being worked on by many developers. If you read my question you'd see that this isn't a viable solution for me.

Comment: I helped you as I could. I have no other idea.

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen to implement a solution based upon the authentication technique described in this blog post:

http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth

If the blog post is no longer live: The gist of it is to extend CI_Controller for each access group that you wish to have on the site. You then extended your controllers from these. The constructor of the extended CI_Controller(s) contain code to check if users are logged-in and/or belong to a specific group.

In addition, I've written a "pre-controller" hook that checks to make sure the Controller to be executed is one of these extended controllers and not a vanilla CI_Controller. This is to whitelist only these "authenticated controllers" within my application.

This ensures that no developer that joins the project accidentally opens up part of the site by using a plain "CI_Controller".